# Paperclip delete image via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I want to delete the image via Ajax.
I'm using Paperclip for the upload.

I learned that for deleting the image all I have to do is to set it to nil.

**Example:**

```
@meth.picture = nil # this works
```

**Error msg:**

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for "nil"):
  app/controllers/meths_controller.rb:116:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/meths_controller.rb:115:in `update'
```

**code:**

```
$(function() {
                $('#delete_image').on("click", function() {
                    $('#image > img').remove();
                    //console.log("??");

                    var url = document.URL.split("/");
                    var meth_id = url[4];
                    console.log(meth_id);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Methoden/'+meth_id,
                        type: 'PATCH',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {"meth": {"picture": "nil"}},
                        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        },
                        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            console.log(" ?? profit");                                                                                                                                                              
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        }
                    });
              });
        });
```

With the help from  Зелёный, I did the following:

```
data: {"meth": "delete_image"}
```

Then in my controller update method:

```
if params[:meth] == "delete_image"
  @meth.picture = nil 
  @meth.save
end
```

Comment: @Зелёный You are right, it seems like I'm sending a string, how could I make that different? The meths_controller.rb is a simple scaffold and nothing else.

Comment: @Зелёный, your solution worked out, if you want you can create an answer and I'll accept it. thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is what you pass string (`(No handler found for "nil")`) to the method `@meth.picture`.

Send instead `"nil"` something like `"delete"` or `"clear"` and check in controller `if params[:meth] == "delete"` do `@meth.picture = nil` else do something other.